# LLDB Python ReadMemory returns NoneType

Tags: python, lldb

I have a script in Python where I check value of x0 register which is a pointer to some memory address and read memory from there. But in my Python script, ReadMemory return None and because of that bytearray function call throws an error. In LLDB console `memory read <x0 value>` works. Code is below:

```py
import random
import lldb

debugger = lldb.SBDebugger.Create()
target = debugger.GetTargetAtIndex(0)


def modify_memory(debugger, command, result, internal_dict):

    thread = debugger.GetThread()
    # if called from console itself, debugger argument type is true but if it comes from breakpoint
    # debugger type == SBFrame. SBFrame has GetThread() method; so debugger above is actually frame
    db = lldb.SBDebugger.Create()
    if thread:
        #db.HandleCommand("print \"a\"")
        frame = thread.GetSelectedFrame()

        # Read the value of register x0
        x0 = frame.FindRegister("x0")
        x0_value = x0.GetValue()
        x0_value = int(x0_value,16)
        print(x0_value)
        # Read memory at the address stored in x0
        memory = process.ReadMemory(x0_value+16+4, 256, lldb.SBError())
        print(memory)
        if memory != None:
            print("finally something!")
            # Modify a random byte in the memory
            random_byte = random.randint(2, 255)
            memory = bytearray(memory)
            memory[random_byte] = random.randint(0, 255)

            # Write the modified memory back to the original location
            process.WriteMemory(x0_value, memory, lldb.SBError())
        
    
        process.Continue()
    else:
        db.HandleCommand("print \"thread NOT found\"")

    process.Continue()
```

I add modify_memory as a command to breakpoints.

I tried to run command from interactive console but did not manage to re-create thread, process etc variables. Also, I add function modify_memory as command but then variable "debugger" come as SBDebugger (which is actually true :) )but if I add this to a breakpoint, "debugger" variable becomes SBFrame which has the method GetThread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the newer command definition form:

```
def command_function(debugger, command, exe_ctx, result, internal_dict):
```

If you define your function that way, lldb will pass an `SBExecutionContext` in the `exe_ctx` parameter that contains the frame/thread/process/target you should act on in the command.

The point is that at any given stop, lldb first queries all the threads, and for each of them that have stopped for a reason, runs the relevant callbacks, then decides whether to stop or not, then computes the selected thread.  So at the time breakpoint callbacks are being run, the selected thread is still the one from the last time the debugee stopped.

The original form was really an oversight in the design.  We kept the old form around for compatibility reasons, but at this point it's unlikely there are any lldb's around that don't include the more useful form.  So that's really the one you want to use.

Comment: Hmmm, interestingly, that throws an error "TypeError: modify_memory() missing 1 required positional argument: 'internal_dict'" when I turn function definition to `def modify_memory(debugger, command, exe_cxt, result, internal_dict)`

Comment: I set internal_dict to None by default and get `target = exe_cxt.GetTarget()
AttributeError: 'SBStructuredData' object has no attribute 'GetTarget'` error as a result

Comment: You shouldn't mess with the internal_dict, that's how lldb handles supporting multiple Python interpreters (one per SBDebugger).

Comment: Not sure about your error, however.  If I define a function mycmd with this signature  in the file cmdfile.py, do `command script import mycmd.py` then `command script add my-command -f cmdfile.mycmd` I don't get errors about missing arguments when I run my-command.  I'd need more details about what you are doing to know why you get this error.

Comment: I try to add this function as a command for breakpoints actually with command  `breakpoint command add -s python -F lldb_machfuzzer.modify_memory 1`. So when a breakpoint hits, modify_memory will start.  But when it is added to breakpoint and run from there, this error is thrown. If it is added as command as you said, it will run but still throws this error,this time twice

Comment: You can do two things.  You can write a Python-based breakpoint callback or a Python-based command.  They have different signatures.  If you want to call some code directly from the breakpoint, use the former, that will get the stack frame that hit the breakpoint directly, and there's no need to use selected entities.  I thought you wanted to use a Python-based command as an lldb command in your callback.  In that case, you need to use the command form that gets passed the SBExecutionContext, since it will get run in a breakpoint context.

Comment: Yeah, that worked! This should be the signature, then. Thanks!